# Calculate full months between dates in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, date-time

I have dates in two columns and I would need to calculate amount of full months between two dates.

I export the spreadsheet from SAP ERP in .xls format but opening with Excel 2010. `DATEDIF` function is not available to me.

The amount of rows is unknown and variable. Dates are always in columns D and E. I need to repeat this operation between once a week to 1-2 times a day. I can live with all months assumed to be 30 days.

For sake of speed I have merely calculated `(E2-D2)/30` but would like to make it more reliable. Formula is preferred, VBA is for interest.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make it accurate you can try out the formula

```
=(YEAR(E2)-YEAR(D2))*12+MONTH(E2)-MONTH(D2)-(DAY(E2)<DAY(D2))
```

the formula should be self explanatory except the last part `-(DAY(E2)<DAY(D2))`, which subtracts one month if it is not a complete month.

Comment: Cheers, will probably save this to a macro.

Answer (score 1):

The formula you already have in place is about as reliable as it can get if you can live with a month averaging 30 days. You could improve it by making sure it only returns the full number

`=int((e2-d2)/30)` will cut off the decimals.